# How to fine tune universal sentence encoder 3 embeddings to own corpus

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub

I would like the fine tune the embeddings produced by googles universal sentence encoder large 3(https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3) to my own corpus.  Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. My current idea is to feed sentence pairs from my corpus to the encoder and then use an extra layer to classify if they are the same semantically.  My trouble is that I am not sure how to set this up as this requires setting up two USE models that share weights, I believe it is called a siamese network.  Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated

```
def train_and_evaluate_with_module(hub_module, train_module=False):
    embedded_text_feature_column1 = hub.text_embedding_column(
      key="sentence1", module_spec=hub_module, trainable=train_module)

    embedded_text_feature_column2 = hub.text_embedding_column(
      key="sentence2", module_spec=hub_module, trainable=train_module)


    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
      hidden_units=[500, 100],
      feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column1,embedded_text_feature_column2],
      n_classes=2,
      optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))

    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)

    train_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_train_input_fn)
    test_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_test_input_fn)

    training_set_accuracy = train_eval_result["accuracy"]
    test_set_accuracy = test_eval_result["accuracy"]

    return {
      "Training accuracy": training_set_accuracy,
      "Test accuracy": test_set_accuracy
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the code of what you've done so far?

Comment: I have added some of the code I am working on.  A couple questions that I have: Will the initial text embedding models be treated as different models rather than the same weights?  How can I save just the fine tuned embedding part of the model?

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/134: initialize one `hub.Module(..., trainable=True)` object and call it twice.